# How to use correctly Assembly.LoadFile?

Tags: c#, .net, assembly-loading

During the execution of an application I need to be able to load an assembly from different locations with the same identity.
I was using Assembly.LoadFrom but this method only loads the first version used and not the rest. After reading on MSDN I figured out that, for this situation, I need to use "Assembly.LoadFile".
My problem is that after having changed the method I'm getting `FileNotFoundException`. How is that possible? It happens with the same path I used before. Also the exceptions appear when trying to use the types defined in the assembly and not from the LoadFile method.

If I explore the returned assembly variable, every member related with the inner types shows exceptions. For example `DefinedTypes`, `ExportedTypes`. Exploring those exceptions I see that for every type the corresponding exception is a `FileNotFoundException` like:

> Could not load file or assembly 'AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the magical world of assembly load contexts! You will have to use `fuslogvw` to see what is going on. Good luck.

Comment: "...and does not resolve dependencies using the load path, as the LoadFrom method does." You may want to set up an `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event handler to see what .NET is missing when you try to access these types.

Comment: please clean solution and try again.